# I am unable to display icon on Phonegap application for iPhone

Tags: iphone, cordova, phonegap-build

I am having problems diplaying icon on iphone. On Android it is displayed properly. I used Phonegap Build to compile the app. This is the code I used in the config.xml file

```
<icon src="images/icon.png"  gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have defined the default icon?

```
<icon src="icon.png" /><!-- default; don't change location! -->
```

Here is the section for iOS, how I use it in my PhoneGap Build projects.

```
<icon src="icon.png" /><!-- default; don't change location! -->
<icon src="icons/ios/classic.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="icons/ios/ipad.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="icons/ios/retina.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="icons/ios/retina_ipad.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
```

And don't change the location of the default icon, like mentioned in the sample (as comment).